# How to stop long operation on QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I've made some research but I couldn't find the answer to why my solution is not working. But to the point.

I've got QWidget as a separate dialog in my app. I'm using this QWidget class to gather paths to files and zip them into one file with ZipLib. To give users some feedback about the progress of the zipping I've added QProgressBar which is updated during zipping. But I've found out that in some cases when files are too big, zipping files are taking very long and makes my app not respond during this time. So my idea was to move the long operation of zipping to another thread using QThread and everything is working fine, zipping is working, and the progress bar is updated BUT there is a problem when I want to cancel the zipping operation. With my current approach action with zipping just don't listen to any of my requests to interrupt the thread and the thread is doing zipping even after I've closed my dialog. I'll show you my approach maybe there is something very trivial but I just can't make to cancel this zipping operation.

tl;dr version:
I can't interrupt QThread with `requestInterruption()` or any other way.

This is my WorkerThread class:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setup(std::string zip, std::vector<std::string> file)
    {
        mZip = zip;
        mFiles = file;
        mActionStopped = false;
    }

    void run() override {
        size_t progressValue = (100 / mFiles.size());

        try
        {
            for (const auto& file : mFiles)
            {
                if (not isInterruptionRequested())
                {
                    Q_EMIT updateTheProgress(progressValue);
                    ZipFile::AddFile(mZip, file);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            Q_EMIT resultReady(false);
        }

        if (not mActionStopped)
        {
            Q_EMIT updateTheProgress(100 - actualProgress); // To set 100%
            Q_EMIT resultReady(true);
        }
    }

    std::string mZip;
    std::vector<std::string> mFiles;
    size_t actualProgress = 0;
    bool mActionStopped;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void resultReady(bool dupa);
    void updateProgress(int value);

public Q_SLOTS:
    void updateTheProgress(int value)
    {
        actualProgress += value;
        Q_EMIT updateProgress(actualProgress);
    }

    void stopWork()
    {
        mActionStopped = true;
    }
};
```

And in my QWidget class I've got something like this:

```
workerThread = new WorkerThread();
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &ZipProjectDialog::zipDone);
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(updateProgress(int)), progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));

connect(btnBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, workerThread, &WorkerThread::requestInterruption);
connect(btnBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, workerThread, &WorkerThread::stopWork);

workerThread->setup(zipFilename, filePathList);
workerThread->start();
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

I've followed [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) documentation with this but `requestInterruption()` is still not working.

If someone has any idea how to resolve this I'll appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run any of this in the debugger to see whether your signal is being emitted, and/or the slot is seeing it?

Comment: @mzimmers Yes, I did and slot is seeing interruption but after zipping is done. Which means even if I click close button in the middle of zipping, zipping is going to end first and then there is an interruption emitted so I can see both "success" and "interrupted" dialogs.

Comment: Try to comment out you real action `Q_EMIT` and `ZipFile::AddFile(mZip, file);` and then 
replace with a simple log output. To see if your `Q_EMIT`or `AddFile` does something unintentionally blocking your thread.

Comment: @LouisGo Thanks, I've checked this but actually ```ZipFile::AddFile(mZip, file);``` is my main operation here. ZipFile is from ZipLib which I use to create .zip file and when I comment it out QThread is doing nothing and also nothing is blocking this thread.

Comment: This is a simple cross test. You want to know why `isInterruptionRequested()` is not working, so the best way is commenting out your main logic `ZipFile::AddFile()` and add a small sleep to simulate the routine. If you may stop the thread by not using  `ZipFile::AddFile()`, then  `ZipFile::AddFile()` is probably the root cause. And we can't tell since we don't have your environment. If that's not the problem, keep commenting out suspicious code and test it.

Comment: @LouisGo Thank you for your advice. I did like you said and there is the same feedback with ```QThread::sleep(20)``` like with ```ZipFile::AddFile(mZip, file);``` which means that during one cycle of sleep I'm pressing the close button and  ```isInterruptionRequested()``` is set to true but log (which I put in my else statement) is showing only after cycle of sleep(20) is ended. To be more specific I've got 10x QThread::sleep(20), I'm canceling after 2nd cycle and there is log after 60s but not in exact time when I'm pressing the button.

Comment: @Rebel Are you adding a single huge file?

Comment: @LouisGo I'm adding few files but some of them can be huge. That's why I need an option to cancel this operation when user will press cancel button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot interrupt the execution of

```
ZipFile::AddFile(mZip, file);
```

itself. It is a single call to a function, and no one checks `isInterruptionRequested()` inside that function.

A simplified example

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run() override
    {
        qDebug() << "starting";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            qDebug() << "loop" << i;
            if (!isInterruptionRequested())
                sleep(5);
            else
                break;
        }
        qDebug() << "finished";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyThread thread;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &thread, [&thread] {
        thread.start();
        QTimer::singleShot(7000 /*7 seconds*/, &thread, [&thread] {
            qDebug() << "interrupting";
            thread.requestInterruption();
        });
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

prints

```
starting
loop 0
loop 1
interrupting
loop 2
finished
```

as expected. And as expected there are a few seconds delay between "interrupting" and "loop 2", and no delay between "loop 2" and "finished".

If you want to interrupt your task more granular, then you have to find a more granular API than ZipFile::AddFile, so you can check `isInterruptionRequested()` regularly even while a single file is archived, or use an external process that can be killed instead.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I've already figure it out thanks to @LouisGo, that unfortunately I can't interrupt ZipFille::AddFile so I just left it like this which mean that if user will click cancel button then zipping will be interrupted only after current iteration of ZipFile::AddFile will be done. Not a most elegant way but for now its okay for me.

Comment: @Rebel I that was why I asked for cross test. To tell whether it's `AddFile()` itself cannot be interrupted.